# Why is my if statement always returning false? (The return value is always 0)

Tags: java

The function 'spd' is used to find the smallest prime divisor of the integer y.
However, when I run the code, no matter what the value of 'y' is, the returned value is always 0.

```
public static BigInteger spd (int y) {

    ArrayList<BigInteger> primes = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();

    int retval;
    int Nth_prime = 10000;
    BigInteger getn;
    BigInteger y2 = BigInteger.valueOf(y);
    BigInteger TWO = new BigInteger("2");
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("1");

    primes.add(TWO);

    int i = 1;

    while (i < Nth_prime) {
        bi = bi.add(TWO);
        if (bi.isProbablePrime(40)) {
            i++;
            primes.add(bi);
        }
    }

    BigInteger zero = new BigInteger ("0");
    BigInteger ret;
    BigInteger one  = new BigInteger ("1");

    for (int n = 0; n < y2.intValue(); n++) {
        if (y2.mod(primes.get(n)).equals(zero)) {
            retval = primes.get(n).intValue();
        }
    }   

    BigInteger returning = BigInteger.valueOf(retval);

    return returning;
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't even compile because variable `retval` is not initialized.

Comment: I've executed the code (initializing variable `retval = 0`) passing `y = 500` and returning value was `5`.

Answer (score 1):

**This is the code with the initialization and with some refactor:**

```
public static BigInteger spd(int y) {

    ArrayList<BigInteger> primes = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();

    int retval = 0;
    int Nth_prime = 10000;
    BigInteger y2 = BigInteger.valueOf(y);
    BigInteger TWO = new BigInteger("2");
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("1");

    primes.add(TWO);

    int i = 1;

    while (i < Nth_prime) {
        bi = bi.add(TWO);
        if (bi.isProbablePrime(40)) {
            i++;
            primes.add(bi);
        }
    }

    BigInteger zero = new BigInteger("0");

    for (int n = 0; n < y2.intValue(); n++) {
        if (y2.mod(primes.get(n)).equals(zero)) {
            retval = primes.get(n).intValue();
        }
    }

    return BigInteger.valueOf(retval);
}
```